# Automatic model binding in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcsf

I've been using asp.net mvc and I like the facility given by UpdateModel & TryUpdateModel. Now I'm developing an application using the Web Client Software Factory. Are there any model binders I can use with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model binders in MVC and very much tied into the MVC infrastructure. While it might be possible to adapt it to work with WebForms, I'm not aware of anybody who's doing it today.